# Creating transition matrices in R using "table" function

Tags: r, matrix

I have a data frame containing 4 columns:
period, ID, category in the current period, category in the next period.

```
period <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
ID <- c('a12', 'a123', 'a1234', 'a12345', 'b12', 'b123', 'b1234', 'b12345', 'c12', 'c123')
category_t0 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 1, 3, 2, 5, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1)
category_t1 <- c(1, 3, 2, 5, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA')
df <- data.frame(period, ID, category_t0, category_t1)
```

I need to create separate transition matrices for each period. I was trying to use "table" function, but cannot figure out how to write in a condition to use a certain period. The following code takes into account all observations in the data frame, while I need to take only values for "period == 1".

```
trans_1to2 = table(df$category_t0, df$category_t1, useNA = c("ifany"))
matrix_1to2 = trans_1to2 / rowSums(trans_1to2)
print(matrix_1to2)
```

[image: My desired output for period 1 should look like this.]

Could anyone share ideas on this?
Also, the real data has 50 periods so I need to create 50 different transition matrices. What would be the best way to do it (e.g. using a loop)?

Thanks!

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide some small set of dummy data  rather than images as that ensures we fully understand the question and can also provide a working answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could subset `df` with `df$period==1` in `[` to get the table for period 1.

```
trans_1to2 = table(df[df$period==1, 3:4])
trans_1to2 / rowSums(trans_1to2)
#           category_t1
#category_t0    1    2    3    4    5   NA
#          1 0.75 0.25 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
#          2 0.00 0.00 1.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
#          3 0.00 0.50 0.00 0.50 0.00 0.00
#          4 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 1.00 0.00
#          5 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 1.00
```

To make it for many periods just add the period also to `table`:

```
trans_1to2 <- table(df[c(3,4,1)])
matrix_1to2 <- proportions(trans_1to2, c(1,3))

matrix_1to2[,,1] #Get first period
#           category_t1
#category_t0    1    2    3    4    5   NA
#          1 0.75 0.25 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
#          2 0.00 0.00 1.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
#          3 0.00 0.50 0.00 0.50 0.00 0.00
#          4 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 1.00 0.00
#          5 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 1.00

matrix_1to2[,,2] #Get second period
#           category_t1
#category_t0 1 2 3 4 5 NA
#          1 0 0 0 0 0  1
#          2 0 0 0 0 0  1
#          3 0 0 0 0 0  1
#          4 0 0 0 0 0  1
#          5 0 0 0 0 0  1
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
period <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
ID <- c('a12', 'a123', 'a1234', 'a12345', 'b12', 'b123', 'b1234', 'b12345', 'c12', 'c123')
category_t0 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 1, 3, 2, 5, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1)
category_t1 <- c(1, 3, 2, 5, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA')
df <- data.frame(period, ID, category_t0, category_t1)

library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("category_"), as.factor)) %>% 
  group_split(period) %>% 
  purrr::set_names(nm = str_c("period_", unique(period))) %>% 
  map(~table(.x$category_t0, .x$category_t1) %>% prop.table(margin = 1))
#> $period_1
#>    
#>        1    2    3    4    5   NA
#>   1 0.75 0.25 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
#>   2 0.00 0.00 1.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
#>   3 0.00 0.50 0.00 0.50 0.00 0.00
#>   4 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 1.00 0.00
#>   5 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 1.00
#> 
#> $period_2
#>    
#>     1 2 3 4 5 NA
#>   1 0 0 0 0 0  1
#>   2 0 0 0 0 0  1
#>   3 0 0 0 0 0  1
#>   4 0 0 0 0 0  1
#>   5 0 0 0 0 0  1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>